# How to make a custom C PyTypeObject work with python's "in" keyword?

Tags: python, c, api

As a simple example, I want to allow this kind of usage in a python script assuming `mycustom_CType` is an instance of my defined `PyTypeObject` in C:

```
print('foo' in mycustom_CType)
```

What slots and functions in `PyTypeObject`'s struct does python need for this to work? I'm guessing possibly `tp_iter` and `tp_iternext` but I can't be sure since the python docs doesn't say that for those 2 struct fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`tp_as_sequence.sq_contains`](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html#PySequenceMethods.sq_contains) member of the type is invoked for containment checking.